# How does one store and find ancestry in a given set of data?

Tags: java, ancestor

What I mean:

Say you input pairs of characters/strings:

```
x y
a b
b x
```

Each left hand object maps to the right hand object as an ancestor.
So, say I then enter a new set of data pairs. This time, I want to find if the first object entered is an ancestor of the second object entered (according to the map I built with the first set of input).

For example, say I enter:

```
a y
```

The program should tell me that a is in fact an ancestor of y.  It doesn't have to show the route, just simply a yes or no. a is an ancestor because it maps to b which maps to x which maps to y.

```
a - b - x - y
```

Could someone explain how something like this is stored and constructed? I have toyed with a BFS but cannot figure out how to map the first input data correctly. Especially, how do I make sure that descendants are mapped properly? Like, I should somehow recognize that the key 'b' is also a descendant of 'a'. Is this done while reading the input? During a BFS? Please help. I really need to understand this, as it has been something I've struggled with a lot. I would appreciate actual examples of data structures in Java, and not just links to BFS algorithms. Believe me, I have read them all. Maybe I'm even wrong about the BFS idea.

I am using a HashMap of ArrayLists to store the first input data.  So, I correctly have the right-hand-side strings mapped to their left hand counterparts, even if the LHS are equal.  I just don't know how to add the descendants that are not explicitly added, but are implied.

Comment: Can an object have multiple children and parents?

Comment: Yes, definitely multiple children, and I am assuming multiple parents.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be a linked list. You could search the list for a. Then traverse the parent linkage from a to b, b to x and x to y. If you exhaust the list and don't find y then you know there is no ancestral relationship.

There are many examples of linked list here (both creating your own as well as using java.util.LinkedList

Or maybe just have your objects implement an interface that defines a method like getParent() which returns a common type or interface or null if no parent exists. Then put the objects in a list. Search for a and then follow the parent object references until you hit null. If you don't find the ancestor in question before then, then the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

I think can stick with your map of child against a list of parents. You just need a recursive function to find if a parent is already an ancestor. look at the following code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class AncestorTracker {

    private final Map<String, List<String>> childToParentMappings = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    public void addChildParentMapping(String child, String parent) {
        List<String> existingParents = childToParentMappings.get(child);
        if (existingParents == null) {
            existingParents = new ArrayList<String>();
            childToParentMappings.put(child, existingParents);
        }
        if (!existingParents.contains(parent)) {
            existingParents.add(parent);
        }
    }

    public boolean isAncestor(String child, String ancestor) {
        boolean result = false;

        if (childToParentMappings.containsKey(child)) {
            List<String> immedidateParents = childToParentMappings.get(child);
            if (immedidateParents.contains(ancestor)) {
                result = true;
            } else {
                for (String immediateParent : immedidateParents) {
                    if (isAncestor(child, immediateParent)) {
                        result = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AncestorTracker ancestorTracker = new AncestorTracker();
        String[][] pairs = { {"x", "y"}, {"a", "b"}, {"b", "x"}, {"a", "y"} };

        for (String[] aPair : pairs) {
            String child = aPair[1];
            String parent = aPair[0];

            if (ancestorTracker.isAncestor(child, parent)) {
                System.out.println(child + " is already a decendent of " + parent); 
            } else {
                ancestorTracker.addChildParentMapping(child, parent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```